# BizTalk 2013 log file to debug EDI application

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013

I am new to BizTalk.  I wrote an application to receive an EDI 850 (Purchase Order) and to output a corresponding xml file in a separate folder location.

In the project I deployed to biz talk I have an 850 schema, my result xml schema, a map from the original EDI 850 to my new xml schema, and a pipeline with a flat file assembler pointing to my new schema.

I set it up like what is explained in the following tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226541.aspx.  I did run through this tutorial first and it worked for me.

I dropped the edi file into my receive folder and it is picked up.  But my result file in the send to folder is empty.

The event viewer does not show any errors.

I would like to know if there is a log file that would show where something may have been configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To RECEIVE an EDI file, you need a receive pipeline with an EDI disassembler.

The EdiReceive pipeline in the EDI BizTalk application is what you are looking for most likely. By default this pipeline does the necessary tracking, so you should be able to see in the "Tracked Message Events".

You should always try to do it step by step:

1. EdiReceive disassemble to XML file and subscribe to that file using a send port.
2. Once this works, try mapping the result with a 'Test Map' using VS. You might notice you did something wrong there.
3. Once this works, deploy your mapping to BizTalk and set it in the send port as an outbound map, so it gets executed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the BizTalk Server Administration Console and look at Tracked message events, that should show you if BizTalk received it and where it went.